# Margin vertical rule on outside margin of twosided memoir

Tags: margins, memoir, double-sided

So I have found this code which puts a rule inside the left margin. How can I get the code to switch to the outside margin on a two sided document? I can't locate the original post, as it was on TeX.exchange. Either way however, the answer did not suggest the alternation of sides.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\VerBar[2]{%
{\color{#1}\rule{#2}{65pt}}
}

\SetBgPosition{-1,0}
\SetBgAngle{90}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgOpacity{0.5}
\SetBgContents{\VerBar{blue}{5cm}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test chapter one}
\lipsum[1-30]\clearpage

\SetBgContents{\VerBar{blue}{5cm}}
\chapter{Test chapter one}
\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Adding from discussion in comments:

Here is a screenshot of the MWE solution you provide. It shows page 4 with color on left side. Shouldn't it be on the right if it is an even page? I am so confused. I hear you loud and clear. And I completely respect your knowledge. But I can't seem to get the desired result.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package documentation contains an example of this sort of thing; I also added the possibility (with the use of a simple boolean switch) to activate/deactivate the background material at wish. Adjust the settings according to your needs:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[contents={},opacity=0.5,scale=1,angle=90,hshift=-2.5cm]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\VerBar[2]{%
  {\color{#1}\rule{#2}{65pt}}}

\newif\ifBgUse

\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifBgUse%
\ifodd\value{page} 
\backgroundsetup{position={current page.north east},vshift=32.5pt,%
contents={\VerBar{blue}{5cm}}}%
\else
\backgroundsetup{position={current page.north west},vshift=-32.5pt,%
contents={\VerBar{blue}{5cm}}}%
\fi%
\BgMaterial%
\fi}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter one}
\lipsum[1-9]\clearpage

\BgUsetrue% activate background material
\chapter{Test chapter two}
\lipsum[1-9]\clearpage

\BgUsefalse% deactivate background material
\chapter{Test chapter two}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the code to use the inner margin:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[contents={},opacity=0.5,scale=1,angle=90,hshift=-2.5cm]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\VerBar[2]{%
  {\color{#1}\rule{#2}{65pt}}}

\newif\ifBgUse

\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifBgUse%
\ifodd\value{page} 
\backgroundsetup{position={current page.north west},vshift=-32.5pt,%
contents={\VerBar{blue}{5cm}}}%
\else
\backgroundsetup{position={current page.north east},vshift=32.5pt,%
contents={\VerBar{blue}{5cm}}}%
\fi%
\BgMaterial%
\fi}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter one}
\lipsum[1-9]\clearpage

\BgUsetrue% activate background material
\chapter{Test chapter two}
\lipsum[1-9]\clearpage

\BgUsefalse% deactivate background material
\chapter{Test chapter two}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that due to the way I opened the document in Okular (using "Facing pages" view), odd-numbered pages appear to the right and even-numbered pages, to the left (in a regular book they are the other way round).

Comment: When I attempt to compile the MWE it rejects it regarding the optional arguments in `background` package.

Comment: @Calhistorian you have an outdated version of the package. Update the package, if possible;  otherwise, I'll add an answer using the old syntax in a few hours ( bed time now).

Comment: @Calhistorian the code as it is now uses the outer margin (left margin on odd-numbered pages, right margin on even-numbered ones).

Comment: Please correct me (again) if I am wrong, but even in your MWE and the images displayed, the colored bar is in the inside margin. Right margin on odd and left on even.

Comment: @Calhistorian please see the numbering on the pages. The image seems to show the inner margin, but that's just due to the arrangement of pages in the viewer I used to obtain the image. If you check the numbering, you'll see that the outer margin is being used (in a normal text, odd-numbered pages go to the left, even-numbered ones, to the right: the image shows them swapped, but as I said that's just the image).

Comment: If I compile the MWE as you have it, Chapter 2 is an odd page with color in the north east corner. Your code states `\ifodd` then `current page.north east`. I of course don't presume to understand the code.

Comment: @Calhistorian precisely. Odd pages normally go to the left side on a regular book, so the first page of Chapter 2 has the mark on the outer margin; the second page of Chpater 2 is an even page, so it goes to the right in a book, and it has the mark on the outer margin. As I explained, my viewer presents facing pages as they appear in the image creating the illusion that the inner margin is being used, but this is not so. Remember, odd-numbered pages go to the left in a book (although in the image they appear to the right)

Comment: @Calhistorian (cont.) and even-numbered pages go to the right in a book (although in the image they appear to the left). In any case, I can provide the code to swap the marks, but then they will show up in the inner margins of a standard book.

Comment: Edited my original question to display the conflict I am having. I compiled your MWE to demonstrate. I suppose whatever the issue however, if you present the opposite code (that which switches the margin) we can stop the insanity. :).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9443/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-calhistorian)