# Alternating Background Image for different chapters in Memoir

Tags: memoir, backgrounds

I have used a background image throughout my book. The code I used evolved from this question and answer (thanks to @GonzaloMedina): "[Margin vertical rule on outside margin of twosided memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121449/margin-vertical-rule-on-outside-margin-of-twosided-memoir)"

My question is I would like to figure out how to shift the colored background box to a new location down the edge of the page for each chapter (7-10 chapters). In addition I want to place the chapter # within the colored box. Is this possible?

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[contents={},opacity=0.5,scale=1,angle=90,hshift=-2.5cm]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\VerBar[2]{%
  {\color{#1}\rule{#2}{65pt}}}

\newif\ifBgUse

\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifBgUse%
\ifodd\value{page} 
\backgroundsetup{position={current page.north east},vshift=32.5pt,%
contents={\VerBar{blue}{5cm}}}%
\else
\backgroundsetup{position={current page.north west},vshift=-32.5pt,%
contents={\VerBar{blue}{5cm}}}%
\fi%
\BgMaterial%
\fi}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter one}
\lipsum[1-9]\clearpage

\BgUsetrue% activate background material
\chapter{Test chapter two}
\lipsum[1-9]\clearpage

\BgUsefalse% deactivate background material
\chapter{Test chapter two}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

Comment: But what's the point of using the code of my answer below in your update? The code does what you required (at least on my system), once `book` is changed to `memoir`. Is there something not working for you?

Comment: Still one problem remains, I have found. It seems that the issue I was having before is there is a conflict when using the `\appendix` command in memoir. I want the appendix to be numbered by letters, but your answer creates a conflict with this. I have 4 appendix chapters. The errors seem to be PGF errors. SAMPLE ERROR: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `A' (in '-A*\LabelSize '). [\chapter]

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry; that was my faul for using \thechapter and not \value{chapter} in some parts of the code. Please see my updated answer for the easy fix: notice also that I in order to cope with the fact that \appendix resets the chapter counter, I defined an auxiliary counter to maintain the appropriate shifting in appendices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply introduce an appropriate horizontal shifting (since the material has previously been rotated), based, for example, on the chapter counter:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[contents={},opacity=0.5,scale=1,angle=90]{background}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{mychap}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\stepcounter{mychap}}{}{}

\newcommand*\VerBar[2]{%
  {\color{#1}\rule{#2}{65pt}}%
  \llap{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{%
    \hspace*{-2.5cm}\raisebox{-2.5cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \Huge\color{white}\bfseries\thechapter}%
    }%
  }%
}

\newif\ifBgUse

\newlength\LabelSize
\setlength\LabelSize{2.5cm}

\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifBgUse%
\ifodd\value{page} 
\backgroundsetup{
  position={current page.north west},
  vshift=-32.5pt,
  hshift=-\value{mychap}*\LabelSize,
  contents={\VerBar{blue}{5cm}}%
  }%
\else
\backgroundsetup{
  position={current page.north east},
  vshift=32.5pt,
  hshift=-\value{mychap}*\LabelSize,
  contents={\VerBar{blue}{5cm}}%
  }%
\fi%
\BgMaterial%
\fi}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter one}
\lipsum[1-9]\clearpage

\BgUsetrue% activate background material
\chapter{Test chapter two}
\lipsum[1-9]

\chapter{Test chapter three}
\lipsum[1-9]

\chapter{Test chapter four}
\lipsum[1-9]\clearpage

\appendix

\chapter{Test appendix one}
\lipsum[1-9]\clearpage

\BgUsefalse% deactivate background material
\chapter{Test appendix two}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[contents={},opacity=0.5,scale=1,angle=90]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand*\VerBar[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[#1] (0,0)--(-5,0)--(-5,2)--(0,2)--cycle;
\draw[white] (-2.5,1)node{\rotatebox{-90}{\Huge \thechapter}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newlength{\shift}
\setlength{\shift}{2.5cm}

\newif\ifBgUse

\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifBgUse%
\ifodd\value{page} 
\backgroundsetup{position={current page.north west},vshift=-1cm,%
contents={\VerBar{blue}{5cm}}}%
\else
\backgroundsetup{position={current page.north east},vshift=1cm,%
contents={\VerBar{blue}{5cm}}}%
\fi%
\BgMaterial%
\fi}

\BgUsefalse

\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{*}}%
  {\mycommandStar}%
  {\mycommandNoStar{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\mycommandStar}[1]{\BgUsetrue
\backgroundsetup{hshift=\shift}
\chapter{#1}
\addtolength{\shift}{-5cm}}
\newcommand{\mycommandNoStar}[1]{\BgUsefalse%
\chapter{#1}}

\begin{document}

\mychapter{Test chapter one}
\lipsum[1-9]\clearpage

\mychapter*{Test chapter two}
\lipsum[1-9]\clearpage

\mychapter*{Test chapter three}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

For having the number of the chapter in the box, I use `tikz` instead of `\rule`.

For having a sweep of the box according to the chapter I defined a new length (shift) which is decreased (to go down) by 5 cm each time a new chapter is started and the `BgUse` is true. For that I just defined a new command `\mychapter` working exactly as `\chapter` (and setting `BgUse` to false) and the starred version of this command `\mychapter*` which will turn `BgUse` true and add the sweeping boxes on the side of the page. It also call the chapter command.

Here is the output for the chapters 2 and 3 (first page):

---

[image: Chapter 2]

---

[image: Chapter 3]

---