# Using two different wallpapers in the same document

Tags: backgrounds, wallpaper

I have a 2-page document (letter) where I want to have a background image on both pages, but not the same image on both.  It seems as though the wallpaper package can only work with one image. Is there a way to use two different images?

Comment: Have you tried the `background` package and and `\if` statement. For example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131824/10898 . Also look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46281/10898

Comment: "the wallpaper package can only work with one image" - Are you sure? You can use `\ThisCenterWallPaper{#1}{#2}` to set wallpaper on the next page only.

Comment: @Shannon -- This solution may be a way to do http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134795/34618

Answer (score 1):

[This TeX.SX answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167741/55879) is good background reading: it shows us how to create a background for a single page using TikZ, though it also requires you to know exactly where the page is going to end. Changing it a little bit produces a macro that sets the background of whatever page it's on:

```
\newcommand*{\PageBackground}[1]{
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[opacity=0.3,inner sep=0pt] at (current
    page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{#1}};
}
```

Since you know that your letter is only two pages, you can call `\Pagebackground{`*image_name*`}` at the beginning of your document (which is on the first page) and at the end (which is on the second). If you want to expand this solution to multiple pages, you'll want to call `\PageBackground` once per page, within a document element that is on the page.

Here's an example document, where `light1.png` and `light2.png` can be replaced by your preferred backgrounds:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand*{\PageBackground}[1]{
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[opacity=0.3,inner sep=0pt] at (current
    page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{#1}};
}

\begin{document}
\PageBackground{light1}
\lipsum[1-7]
\PageBackground{light2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As [masu mentioned]{[Using two different wallpapers in the same document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139612/using-two-different-wallpapers-in-the-same-document#comment315045_139612)}, **wallpaper** certainly supports different backgrounds in a single document:

[image: felines of all stripes]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wallpaper,graphicx,kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \ThisCenterWallPaper{1}{tiger}
  \kant[1-6]
  \ThisCenterWallPaper{1}{cath-gadael-chartref}
\end{document}
```

If you want something like conditional inclusion, then something like the **background** package is more straightforward and flexible. But for a simple, two-page document, **wallpaper** is a lighter, simpler choice.