# How to use background image in LaTeX?

Tags: graphics

I am generating one report where I need to use background image. But I found that image always starts leaving some margin space to left side.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
 Some content
\ThisLRCornerWallPaper{1.0}{image.jpg}
\end{document}
```

How can I use background image covering whole page?

Comment: Not having access to image.jpg I can only guess.  You might try one of the images in   \usepackage{mwe}.  Anyway,    \ThisLRCormenrWallPaper preserves the aspect ratio and will leave a margin on the left if it hits the top.  To ignore the aspect ratio, use    \ThisTileWallPaper{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}{image.jpg}

Answer (score 115):

You can do this in number of ways. I will show three more methods.

With `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
 Some content
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[opacity=0.3,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}};
\clearpage
text
\end{document}
```

With `eso-pic`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
 Some content
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}};
\clearpage
text
\end{document}
```

`\AddToShipoutPictureBG` (instead of  `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*`) puts the background in all pages.

With `background` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
color=black,
opacity=0.4,
angle=0,
contents={%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}
  }%
}
\begin{document}
 \BgThispage
 Some content
 \clearpage
 text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Remark: the functionality of `background` is based on `tikz`. So, you show actually two methods. ;-)

Comment: For those, like me, that came here looking for a solution for .Rmd, the second one works, however it will insert a ';' into the document asif it were a character, and can be removed. I'm not sure if this is a special operator that LaTeX sees and .Rmd doesn't. The geometry argument also doesn't seem to be required.

Comment: What does * do at the end of \AddToShipoutPictureBG?

Comment: @bkarpuz From the manual of `eso-pic`: "`\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` works like `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` but only for the current page. "

Comment: @DaveRGP: This ";" comes from the command, you can safely remove it. Likely just a copy & paste error

Comment: The first way, with tikz, puts the background image *on top* of the page's content, which might not be what you want. The other two ways worked exactly as expected though.

Comment: The tikz way _sometimes_ results with an image at the wrong height that would take onely like 10% of the page height instead of full height for me. Maybe it goes into a conflict with fancybox,fancyhdr packages.

Comment: Is {{example-picture}} basically {{example-picture.jpg}}?

Comment: The `background` package gives me a fatal error about "Undefined control sequence. l.23 \pgfsyspdfmark". Can't figure out what that is. The `\AddToHook` [solution from adam.baker below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583319/107500) worked on the first try and didn't need imports.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a solution that uses the (relatively) new `\AddToHook` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
    \put (0in,-\paperheight){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{mybg.pdf}}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

(The `background` package now gives a warning because it uses deprecated macros.)

Comment: Such a simple solution to underlay with a pdf. No extra packages needed.

Answer (score 1):

Something I figured out that I looked a while for what how to skip a background image for a specific page. I have discovered the best way to do this is with:

```
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=0.1,
color=black,
opacity=0.1,
angle=0,
contents={%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{Picture.png}
  }%
}

----- Page Wanting to Omit -----

Blah Blah Blah

\NoBgThispage % <------- Skips for current page
\BgThispage % <------- Starts bg again for next page

Blah Blah Blah
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/230328)