# tikzpicture image on second page

Tags: tikz-pgf

This tex file generates a full-width image of a blue square on the second page, after a completely blank page. What causes the extra page and how to prevent it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0pt] (blue) at (0,0)
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{b0.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)

pgf 3.0.1a

Comment: Is `b0.png` a blue square? Try replacing `b0.jpg` with `example-image`, do you see the same problem?

Comment: If the image is so high that it can't fit on the page, LaTeX will try and fail to place it on the first page, and then put it on the second page. What are the dimensions of that image?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. image dimensions are 150x200 pixels. Is there some way to force the first attempt?

Comment: Can't you just resize the image? If it's just a blue rectangle, then that shouldn't be a problem. Make sure the proportions are the same as that of the papersize (A4 or letter). But what is your purpose here? If you want a blue page, there is `\pagecolor{blue}`.

Comment: @caverac `example-image` only uses the first page. I would like to cover the page, even if some of the image does not fit in. I guess my issue is with `height=\paperheight` or greater? If i set that height i get the same problem again

Comment: @TorbjørnT. The purpose is to cover the page with an image,

Comment: Try for example the methods described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167719/how-to-use-background-image-in-latex

Comment: You can also use eso-pic for that purpose.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, the methods there solve my problem. instead of the `tikzpicture`environment, using `\tikz` works.

Comment: `\tikz` is a shortform for the `tikzpicture` environment, so that's not the key difference. The clue is in the `remember picture, overlay` options, and using the `current page` node (described in section 17.13.2 in the `pgf`/TikZ manual).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
 \AtPageLowerLeft{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0pt] (blue) at (0,0)
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-10x16}};
\end{tikzpicture}}}
%
~\clearpage
second page
\end{document}
```

If you really want only one page, remove `\clearpage` and the stuff below it.

Answer (score 1):

i cant reproduce your problem ... if you like to have this picture on page center, see if this is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[inner sep=0pt] (blue) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{b0.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

you need to compile at least two times.

[image]

**addendum:** full page image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[inner sep=0pt] (blue) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{b0.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe it is caused by height exceeding a certain value. Please tell me if you still cannot reproduce my issue once you set `height=\paperheight`

Comment: do you can't test this yourself? in my test this work fine, however not to forget to compile document at list twice :-)