# Page background in ShareLaTeX

Tags: graphics, backgrounds, sharelatex

How can I add an image as background in ShareLaTeX?

Comment: [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Does [How to use background image in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167741/124842) works with sharelatex?

Answer (score 2):

...just like you would in any LaTeX environment. Here's an option using [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \includegraphics[width = \paperwidth, height = \paperheight]{example-image}%
  }%
}

\lipsum% Your document

\end{document}
```

The starred version places content in the background on the *current page* only.