# How put picture in background pages the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a simple Latex code

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}
\section{Section One Three}
\section{Section One Four}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}
\section{Section Two Three}

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\section{Section Three One}
\section{Section Three Two}
\section{Section Three Three}
\section{Section Three Four}
\section{Section Three Five}

\chapter{Chapter 4}
\section{Section 4 One}
\section{Section 4 Two}
\section{Section 4 Three}
\section{Section 4 Four}
\section{Section 4 Five}

\chapter{Chapter 5}
\section{Section 5 One}
\section{Section 5 Two}
\section{Section 5 Three}
\section{Section 5 Four}
\section{Section 5 Five}

\chapter{Chapter 6}
\section{Section 6 One}
\section{Section 6 Two}
\section{Section 6 Three}
\section{Section 6 Four}
\section{Section 6 Five}

\chapter{Chapter 7}
\section{Section 7 One}
\section{Section 7 Two}
\section{Section 7 Three}
\section{Section 7 Four}
\section{Section 7 Five}

\end{document}
```

How I can put image (across the whole page) in background of all content pages (if there are more pages) like this:

[image]

If someone knows the solution and makes an example, I will be very grateful.
I would like that the solution to be with Tikz package.

Comment: You can use the `background` package (based on TikZ) as in, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167719/how-to-use-background-image-in-latex (and use `\backgroundsetup{contents={}}` to switch off the background after the TOC).

Comment: You should take a look at the `eso-pic` package.

Answer (score 3):

With [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    % Your background image here
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}%
  }%
}%
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}
\section{Section One Three}
\section{Section One Four}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}
\section{Section Two Three}

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\section{Section Three One}
\section{Section Three Two}
\section{Section Three Three}
\section{Section Three Four}
\section{Section Three Five}

\chapter{Chapter 4}
\section{Section 4 One}
\section{Section 4 Two}
\section{Section 4 Three}
\section{Section 4 Four}
\section{Section 4 Five}

\chapter{Chapter 5}
\section{Section 5 One}
\section{Section 5 Two}
\section{Section 5 Three}
\section{Section 5 Four}
\section{Section 5 Five}

\chapter{Chapter 6}
\section{Section 6 One}
\section{Section 6 Two}
\section{Section 6 Three}
\section{Section 6 Four}
\section{Section 6 Five}

\chapter{Chapter 7}
\section{Section 7 One}
\section{Section 7 Two}
\section{Section 7 Three}
\section{Section 7 Four}
\section{Section 7 Five}

\end{document}
```

`\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{<stuff>}` adds `<stuff>` to the `B`ack`G`round of the current page while the unstarred version `\AddToShipoutPictureBG{<stuff>}` adds `<stuff>` to the current as well as subsequent pages. You can remove any `B`ack`G`round material using `\ClearShipoutPictureBG`.

Comment: Note that the OP asked for a background picture in all pages of the TOC, which I think can be done with your suggestion of the unstarred `\AddtoShipoutPictureBG` followed by a `\ClearShipoutPictureBG` after the TOC.

Comment: @Marijn: Exactly like I suggest at the end of my answer.

Comment: indeed, I just tried to point out to the OP that this part of your answer would fit his needs (whereas the MWE and the screenshot only show a background for the first page).