# Having more backgrounds

Tags: backgrounds

I have a document with a background image, this is the background setup:

```
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
    scale=1,
    opacity=1,
    angle=0,
    contents=
    {%
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{../images/paper}
    }% 
}
```

Now what I would like to do it is to use a different background image in this way:

- All the pages have a background (the one `paper`)
- some pages will have different backgrounds (so let's say page 1 `paper2`, page 5 `paper3`, and so on) these different backgrounds are not the same.

How could I do this?

I tried using the `\begin{figure}` but because these pages are (most of the times) `\part` or `\chapter` and so on, the image was not printed in the page but in the next one.

Thanks in advance, have a nice day!

Comment: Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139612/using-two-different-wallpapers-in-the-same-document?rq=1, there you can find references to other solutions with `background` package but also the suggestion for `wallpaper` which could be of easier use in this case